# Track the sequence of nodes that leads to the goal outcome in a binary decision tree?

Tags: python, tree, binary-tree, nodes, decision-tree

I have implemented a binary decision tree in Python to solve a pretty standard knapsack problem: there is a collection of objects, each with an associated weight and value, and objects must be selected to maximize the value, subject to a weight constraint.

I see how to return the maximum value, but am struggling to find a clever way to return the identities of the objects that yielded the maximum value.

Right now, I'm creating a "string vector", so to speak, with "1"s and "0"s representing the choice to either pack or not pack a certain object.  The first "1" or "0" in the string vector represents the decision that was made for the object that corresponds to the first object in the list of objects, and so on.

Is there a better way to do this?

The code I have written:

```
def knapsack(weightList, valueList, availableWeight, index):
    if index == 0:
        if weightList[index] <= availableWeight:
            return valueList[index], '1'
        else:
            return 0, '0'
    else:
        reject, rVector = knapsack(weightList, valueList, availableWeight, index - 1)
        rVector += "0"
        if weightList[index] <= availableWeight:
            take, tVector = knapsack(weightList, valueList, availableWeight - weightList[index], index - 1)
            take += valueList[index]
            tVector += "1"
        else:
            take = -1

        if take > reject:
            return take, tVector
        else:
            return reject, rVector

weightList = [1, 2, 6, 5, 8, 3, 7, 2, 4, 7, 1]
valueList = [2, 5, 4, 6, 7, 8, 2, 4, 5, 6, 8]
availableWeight = 5
index = len(weightList) - 1

maxValue, vector = knapsack(weightList, valueList, availableWeight, index)
print maxValue
print vector
```

The output is:

```
18
10000100001
```

Answer (score 0):

If the string ends up containing mostly "0" with a few "1", then it's much better to return a Python set object.  Once you got the result as a set, it still allows you to decide efficiently if an index is in the set or not --- so that there was little advantage to using a string of flags in the first place.

Note that sets are mutable, which may create confusion if implemented incorrectly in your algorithm.  I would recommend preferring 'frozenset' over 'set'.